# Looking for a way to fix my program with if and elif statements

Tags: python, if-statement, statements

I am trying to write a simple program, where python counts the number of characters in your name and decdes how cool your name is.
trying to learn if and elif statements...
this is what I have so far

P.S. i am using python 2.7

```
def main():
    print"This program will tell who has a cooler name on a scale of 1-10"
    print""
    name=input("Enter your name: ")
    if len(name)<=4:
        print"on a scale of 1-10 your name is a 2! what a lame name..."
    elif (len(name)>4) and (len(name)<=7):
        print"That is a cool name you deserve a 8/10! Awesome!"
    elif len(name)>7:
        print"you are a 10/10, no one has a better name than you!"

main()
```

Comment: Worst formatting ever.  Too dense to be worth anyones time.  Enter it using the proper code conventions!

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: If you are asking why this won't work, with `elif` you need a final `else` that defaults to when every elif fails.

Comment: @Matt:  Good advice, but harsh tone for a beginner.

Comment: @PepperoniPizza:  No `else` needed if all conditions already covered. In this case they are.

Comment: @Steven Rumbalski haha sorry!  I forget how monotone everything comes off online!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
n = len(name)  # it might be wise to store this

if n <= 4:     # as you have already
    ...
elif n <= 7:   # you already know n > 4 here; no need to test for that
    ...
else:          # you already know n > 7 here; this should be else
    ...
```

Also, since you're using Python 2.7, you want [`raw_input()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) instead of `input()`.